# Simplifying sum of falling factorials

Tags: algorithm-analysis, discrete-mathematics

I wrote the worst algorithm in the world.
Doesn't matter what it does. I have just a question about folding formula for it's time complexity into some shorter form which would be easier to compute.
So I concluded that the equation for the number of operations is as follows:

$$n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \dots + n!\,.$$

**Can we fold this sequence to some nice equation which will give us exact number of operations needed to complete this algorithm?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure mathematics with no computational content in the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave the closed form for the number of operations:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1) = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} = n! \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m!}.
$$
We can estimate this sum as follows:
$$
n! \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m!} =
n! \left(e - \sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}\right) = 
en! - 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} - \cdots = \\
en! - 1 - O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

Comment: The "order of complexity" is $\Theta(n!)$. For the rest, look up material on *asymptotic notation*.